# Cannot cmd + click to reach Laravel development server

Tags: php, laravel, macos, visual-studio-code

I've just set up my first Laravel project playgrounds and am supposed to test open the development server. When I cmd + Click, nothing happens.

I have restarted VSCode and reopened this project several times.

```
    myname-MacBook-Pro:Lectures myname$ php artisan serve
    Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

No error messages, but the basic Laravel window doesn't open. I'm not sure if it is a permissions thing, or even how I would change it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you visited http://127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser of choice? If you have, and it didn't work, then something was logged. Try checking in storage/logs for a logfile and paste any error messages with matching timestamps here.

Comment: I checked it in Chrome and it works. Just not able to cmd + click from inside VSCode